# can't download some files via cmd but can download with browser

Tags: unix, centos, bazel

I met this weird problem several times, for instance, I would like to bazel some file by this command: `bazel build -c opt tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb:ptb_word_lm` ,the cmd shows it is downloading some file:

```
INFO: Downloading from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/six/six-1.10.0.tar.gz#md5=34eed507548117b2ab523ab14b2f8b55: 0B
```

Then it stuck and timed out:

```
Connection timed out and referenced by '//external:six'.
ERROR: Loading failed; build aborted.
INFO: Elapsed time: 128.666s.
```

However I can open this downloading link in my browser and download the file successfully like this:

[image]

Comment: Are there any proxies involved ?

Comment: Yes, I set a proxy in the network settings of the centos system, so I think the proxy may have same influence on the command line and my browser

Comment: You should definitely work on the `may` and `think` and turn it into a `it is` and `know` ... If you need a proxy and one of your applications is not able to connect to the Internet it is likely that this application does not know about the proxy.